# Subsetting data from R data frame using incremental variable names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an R data frame, `df`, with column names `V1, V2, V3...V1000`. I need to subset `df` by selecting every 20th column, that is, `V1, V21, V41, V61` through end of columns.

I think this can be done using dplyr's `select(df, num_range("V", val))`, but am stumped how to iterate val through 1000 columns, stepping by 20.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `seq` function with `dplyr`'s `select` and `num_range` as below:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(3000), nrow = 3))
df %>% select(num_range("V", seq(1, 1000, by = 20)))
```

Answer (score 1):

u can use some function like this.Here nskip=20 as u want to skip 20 columns

```
FOO <- function(data, nSubsets, nskip)
{
 outList <- vector("list", length = nSubsets)
 totcol <- ncol(data)
 for (i in seq_len(nSubsets))
 {
   colsToGrab<- seq(i, totcol, nSkip)
   outList[[i]] <- data[,colsToGrab ] 
 }
return(outList)
}
```

Comment: The person wants a solution.Its not necessary he wants to use only dplyr. @akrun

Comment: Yes, I understand that, so I posted a base R solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
df[seq(1, ncol(df), 20)]
```